# Player acts without seeing prior action

Tags: tournament, nlhe, sng

Tournament (either SNG/MTT) where most players are 15-20BB and shove/fold range.

UTG+1 shoves 15BB
Folds to SB. SB completes the blinds, not seeing the initial shove

What would the ruling on the action be, and what would it depend on?
- SB stack size? I heard that rulings are more lenient when tournament life is on the line.
- UTG vocalises all-in vs pushes chips in.
- Dealer giving all-in player the all-in chip?
- SB throwing in one chip, SB pulling back his small blind and putting in the big blind, SB says call?

I get that the official rules say that this is a call, although in my personal experience, TDs tend to be lenient if no ill intention is present (i.e. obviously not an angleshoot). Also, this was a home game with no dealer, and the table didn't have the line to push the chips over, hence the confusion. Although im interested to know how a casino would handle this as well.

Comment: You understand it well. Yes, it's a call by the rules. Yes, a TD might let you off the hook if the initial shove was hard to see / not announced / etc., and if your call did not cause any further action.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the previous answers, in my experience TD's tend to be lenient in this situation one time if any.  However, many factors are at play here.  As stated above the primary reason for leniency is the player not having made the error before.  Also important is the overall behavior of the player, the stage in the tournament, and the mood at the table.

No need to upvote I'm simply adding some thoughts to the above answers to which I agree.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't vote this answer up, but I could not answer it better then the OP did.

> the official rules say that this is a call, although in my personal experience, TDs tend to be lenient if no ill intention is present (i.e. obviously not an angleshoot).

It is a call and they will often let the player off the hook. However the tend to get more terse with the rule when the player is a repeat offender, or the players action caused some other action behind him. (For example the next player says I am all in, the ruling is going to tend to go against the space cadet more often). Of course I am going to raise hell if I am the bettor, I believe that when someone makes a mistake they own it.

Comment: Agree, altho its hard for the bettor to say anything since its a tourney and generally, everyone folding is a better outcome. So it becomes one of those moments where if you protest a lenient decision, you're risking it becoming a call, but if you dont protest, then people behind the offender can see it as weakness.